# 3D heat diffusion equation in terms of convolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

The solution to 1-D heat equation can be expressed via 1-D convolution. More formally, let $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -k \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}$, then we can find a solution $u = \int f(s)h_t(x-s)ds$.

However, when we consider the cartesian 3D coordinates ($\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -k \Delta u$), why cannot the solution be expressed as a convolution in 3 dimensions?

Thank you.

Comment: It can be, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I can't seem to understand the how link illustrates 3D convolution. Can you please elaborate with more details and put it as an answer, so I can clearly understand it? Thanks a lot.